# Can .htaccess rules be cleaned-up?

Tags: .htaccess

I am helping with a project and noticed the following rules in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-projectdomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-projectdomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.new-projectdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I'm not an expert on this but it looks somewhat redundant, I just can't put my finger on it.Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-projectdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.new-projectdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Wow, that does look much cleaner. What's the new NE flag for?

Comment: `NE` (no-escaping) flag is a good-to-have flag to avoid issues when URL has special characters.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just noticed that I messed up original post, corrected now. Apparently the first part is a redirect from some old domail to the new one, while the other two rules force to use https and www

Comment: It works but now it removes www. I think the intent was to always have it.

Comment: Ah sorry, try it now.